# How do you prevent Jquery $(foo) from overriding the default parameters of function you pass it

Tags: jquery, default-parameters

Jquery has a on ready function. This function takes a callback function and it passes itself as a argument to the callback. This overrides the default parameter of the callback function. How can I prevent this?

```
$((tibet="free") => console.log(tibet))
```

output =>  function()
desired => "free"

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't, the arguments for jquery handler functions are set by jquery. You have to meet their contract.

The better answer is to achieve what you want, you need to wrap it in another function.

The only context that this question makes sense for me is if you have a pre-existing function, somefunc() which takes an argument. What you want is basically:

```
  $((tibet="free") => somefunc(tibet))
```

This can be achieved with an anonymous function,

```
  $(() => somefunc("free))
```